# Selecting an account for saving contacts

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I am making a phone book application.

I can see some of contacts has different **ACCOUNT_TYPE_AND_DATA_SET** (com.whatsapp, com.viber.voip, com.google, com.android.huawei.sim, com.android.huawei.phone etc).

Here is the question: how can I get the list of available **accounts** (Authorities) for saving contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AccountManager` service for that:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
   Log.d(TAG, account.type + " / " + account.name);
}
```

Note, requires the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, if you're targeting Android M and above, you'll alse need to ask the user for this permission via the `Runtime Permissions` model.

**UPDATE**

To skip all accounts that don't support contacts at all, or do support contacts but are read only (like Viber and Whatsapp):

```
final SyncAdapterType[] syncs = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType sync : syncs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter: " + sync.accountType);
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals(sync.authority)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter that supports contacts: " + sync.accountType);
        if (sync.supportsUploading()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter that supports contacts and is not read-only: " + sync.accountType);
            // we'll now get a list of all accounts under that accountType:
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(sync.accountType);
            for (Account account : accounts) {
               Log.d(TAG, account.type + " / " + account.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to explore the other good stuff in [`SyncAdapterType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncAdapterType.html) like `isUserVisible` that you might wanna check as well.

Comment: I can get all accounts by this way. But which of them can I use for saving contacts? For example, I have 3 accounts (google, whatsapp, viber) but actually I can save contacts only on google account (also at Local Phone Storage and Sim Card).