# How to get all available accounts (including multi-SIM cards) that a contact can be saved on?

Tags: android, android-contacts, sim-card, android-account

### Background

I'm working on an app that on one of its screens, it lets the user to save a contact into any account the user wishes, just like on Google's Contacts app and on various built-in Contacts apps of various manufacturers.

I've checked on various apps what they offer:

1. Google's Contacts app offers to save to: Phone, Google accounts
2. "Honor Magic4 pro" built-in contacts app offers to save to: Phone, Google accounts and SIM card (including the second SIM card if it's available)
3. For a third party app called "Simple Contacts", it offers to save to Google, Phone, and SIM card/s (which is good), but also to illogical accounts such as Duo and Meet (which is bad).

### The problem

There are actually 2 issues:

1. Getting only the accounts that users are supposed to save to
2. Offer to save to SIM card, including when the device has multiple SIM card slots

### What I've tried and found

The app already has code that deals with most use cases, but not in a general way:

First, it gets the Google accounts by just using:

```
val accountManager = AccountManager.get(context)
val gmailAccountsType = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")
```

Then using the same function, it gets other types of accounts that are hard-coded, that are considered exchange-type (example is ""com.android.exchange").
`accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")`.

To save to device the account-name and account-type are considered null.

And, lastly, for SIM card (just one) it uses "SIM" as account-name and "com.android.contacts.sim" as account-type. That's even though it seems there are more account-types that mean it's of the SIM-card (such as "vnd.sec.contact.sim").

So that's not good enough. I want a general solution that is similar to what's built-in, yet not as broad as on "Simple Contacts" app.

For the accounts, I tried to use [ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#getSyncAdapterTypes()), based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654589/878126). But it gives me bad results:

1. When "supportsUploading" check, it returns me Telegram account too, and not just Google.
2. When using "isUserVisible", it returns an even larger collection of accounts to save to: Google, Telegram, Duo, Meet, WhatsApp.

```
ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes().forEach { syncAdapterType ->
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY == syncAdapterType.authority && syncAdapterType.supportsUploading) {
        accountManager.getAccountsByType(syncAdapterType.accountType).forEach { account ->
            Log.d("AppLog", account.type + " / " + account.name)
        }
    }
}
```

As for the issue of getting how to save to SIM card/s, I tried to find how it's done in the "Simple Contacts" (it's open sourced, [**here**](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Contacts)), but I failed (too many files and too complex to look for this)

### The questions

Without hard-coded values of checking:

1. How can I get the accounts that a contact can be saved on, similar to the built-in Contacts apps of Google and others (without accounts that users aren't supposed to save to) ?
2. What's the correct way to find the accounts data for SIM cards, including when there are multiple SIM cards that the user can save to?